Taking wine samples from HK to Shenzhen
I need to take 10 bottles of wine from Hong Kong to Shenzhen. They're samples for a tasting. Will it be possible to take them there by train or boat? Will Customs have any problem with 10 bottles of wine? Thank you.

Probably it is good to contact the custom authorities in advance, to get more information. This site is more about tourism and travel, not very much on commercial relations. Samples may get tax free (and maybe some conditions), .e.g. clear labels, so nobody will resell it, etc. But if you intend to do it only once, it may cost less to just ship them and pay normal import taxes as you find the the answer
